# Tomcat8 user Memcached Config Session Share ,but Can`t Start ,I User Tomat7 is right

Tags: session, tomcat, memcached, tomcat8

tomcat config : Manager className="de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager" memcachedNodes="n1:127.0.0.1:11211" sticky="true" sessionBackupAsync="false" lockingMode="none" transcoderFactoryClass="de.javakaffee.web.msm.serializer.javolution.JavolutionTranscoderFactory"

user Jar: couchbase-client-1.0.1.jar
 javolution-5.4.5.jar 
jettison-1.3.2.jar 
memcached-session-manager-1.6.5.jar 
memcached-session-manager-tc7-1.6.5.jar 
msm-javolution-serializer-1.6.5.jar 
spymemcached-2.10.3.jar

error:

```
 Error manager.start() org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager[]] 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5187) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) 

at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:697) at 
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1071) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1722) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationSessionCookieConfig.getSessionCookieName(Lorg/apache/catalina/Context;)Ljava/lang/String; at 

de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager.getSessionCookieName(MemcachedBackupSessionManager.java:814) at de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedSessionService.startInternal(MemcachedSessionService.java:441) at de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager.startInternal(MemcachedBackupSessionManager.java:509) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ... 12 more
```

Tomcat8 user Memcached Config Session Share ,but Can`t Start ,I User Tomcat7 is right,How to resolve?

Answer (score 2):

You must use `memcached-session-manager-tc8*.jar` in Tomcat 8. The exception is complaining about `getSessionCookieName` which was removed in Tomcat 8.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/deprecated-list.html